# Change automatically keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, udev

I use custom keyboard layout. I have this script for setting it:

```
#!/bin/bash
setxkbmap -verbose us -variant altgr-intl
xmodmap -verbose ~/.myxmodmap
```

The problem is, that plugging the keyboard will somehow cancel this setting and I'm again in stardart us ascii.

I created an udev rule, so that when the keyboard is plugged, it will run my script, but I can't get the environment of the script right, it doesn't have access to X server capabilities, it wouldn't change my keyboard layout.

Output from `xmodmap`, when ran from udev rule:

```
Using command line, ignoring X server
```